# How to make the bullets to be firing towards a target?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShootBullets : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float bulletDistance;
    public bool automaticFire = false;
    public float fireRate;
    public Rigidbody bullet;

    private float gunheat;
    private bool shoot = false;
    private GameObject bulletsParent;
    private GameObject[] startpos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bulletsParent = GameObject.Find("Bullets");
        startpos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Fire Point");
    }

    private void Fire()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < startpos.Length; i++)
        {
            Rigidbody bulletClone = (Rigidbody)Instantiate(bullet, startpos[i].transform.position, startpos[i].transform.rotation, bulletsParent.transform);

            bulletClone.velocity = transform.forward * bulletDistance;
            Destroy(bulletClone.gameObject, 0.5f);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (automaticFire == false)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Fire();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (shoot == true)
            {
                Fire();

                shoot = false;
            }
        }

        if (gunheat > 0) gunheat -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (gunheat <= 0)
        {
            shoot = true;
            gunheat = fireRate;
        }
    }
}
```

now the bullets firing up the air and i want the bullets to fire to a target with physics.

the main goal later is to make some kind of side mission where the player third person view should shoot on object and if and when hitting the object the object will fall down and then the player will be able to pick it up.

Comment: Well, you don't have a Target to fire to, which is fine, but apparently you forward vector is facing up in the air.  Have you tried transform.left or transform.up, etc.?

Comment: @jiveturkey I added a new Transform variable name target and changed the line to this : bulletClone.AddForce((target.position - transform.position) * bulletDistance); and using the rigidbody on the bullet with physics and the bulletDistance is set to 350 in the editor. it's seems to be working fine but i wonder if there is a way to calculate the needed bulletDistance according to the distance from the target and set it automatic ? i mean to calculate in the script the bulletDistance automatic.

Comment: `Vector3.Distance (object1.transform.position, object2.transform.position);`

Comment: @jiveturkey last question. why when the bullets hit the target in this case a 3d cube the cube is not moving ? the bullets have a rigidbody and use gravity is enabled  true.  and the bullets also have a capsule collider.  the cube have the regular box collider. i want to use physics so when hitting the target the target will move with the physics like rolling depending on the shooting force.

Comment: Not really sure.  Make sure your bullets have a mass and your cubes aren't too massive.  If you have a bullet of mass 0.001 and your cube has a mass of 3000 it's like a fly hitting a wall.

Comment: It seems to be working now i added the cube a rigidbody too so the bullets have a rigidbody and collider and same the cube rigidbody and collider the problem now is that the player moving with the cube and duck i will try to solve the colliding problems.